# Craft license: what is considered a "dev-sounding subdomain"?

Tags: license

On the license enforcement help page, it says there are a number of checks to determine whether or not a domain is public. One of those checks is the following:

*Does it have a dev-sounding subdomain (e.g. ‘dev’, ‘local’, ‘loc’, ‘test’, ‘testing’, ‘stage’, or ‘staging’)?*

My question is, is there a sure-fire way of determining whether or not a subdomain is dev-sounding? For instance, what if my subdomain has the string 'staging' (e.g. http://staging-subdomain.mysite.com). Or what if it was just an unconventional sounding subdomain (e.g. http://www-next.mysite.com)?

Answer (score 4):

`http://staging-subdomain.mysite.com` would be considered a dev domain because we look for any of those keywords in the subdomain part of the URL.

`http://www-next.mysite.com` would be considered a public domain because it does not meet any of the [criteria](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/how-craft-license-enforcement-works#how-do-we-determine-craft-is-running-on-a-public-domain).